# Ubuntu 10.10 'Command not found' for python script

Tags: ubuntu, shell, python

I have a python script 'monty.py' with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

in the first line.  When I run monty.py in the terminal, I get

```
monty.py: command not found
```

I am in the correct directory, and I also have chmod'ed it to be executable.  Why won't this run?  I am running Ubuntu 10.10 in vmware player.

Edit: Also, when I run /usr/bin/env python from the command line, the python interpreter starts up.  So it is in the right place.

Edit edit:  I figured it out.  Apparently I don't know how to use chmod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
python /path/to/monty/monty.py
```

Or

```
cd /path/to/monty
./monty.py
```

To execute it the second way (./) the monty.py file must be marked as executable:

```
chmod +x /path/to/monty/monty.py
```

Comment: It runs when I use `python monty.py`.  I just don't want to type "python" every time. Also `./monty.py` doesn't work, see my comment above.

Comment: See my edit about chmod +x

Comment: Did that before I asked the question.

Comment: Try issuing this command: `which python` and verify that the output matches the path you specified in monty.py (`/usr/bin/env python`)

Comment: `which python` gives me `/usr/bin/python`.  I tried changing the first line in the file, still no dice.

Answer (score 0):

Unless . (the current directory) is in your path, you won't search in the current directory for the file you're running EVEN THOUGH it's in your current directory.  Instead, try running `./monty.py`

Comment: Stupid comment formatting.
`./monty.py
bash: ./monty.py: Permission denied
sudo ./monty.py
sudo: /.monty.py: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

Did you create monty.py in a windows text editor? If so, try `dos2unix monty.py`

If the file has `<cr><nl>` endings, then the system will see `#!/usr/bin/env python\r` and "python\r" can't be found.

Comment: Written in gedit on ubuntu.

Comment: @Java, just to check, what does `head -1 monty.py | od -c` show you as the line ending?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python\n`

Comment: @Java, please update the question with the current state. I understand that `./monty.py` gives "permission denied" and `monty.py` gives "command not found". Is that right? You might want to show us an `ls -l` listing of the file.